# Cast multiple comma separated values

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, psql

I am running the following **REDSHIFT** query on my table -

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM table
WHERE a in( 303823703001,303823719403,303823675303);
```

I get the following error -

> (null) types character varying and bigint cannot be matched

So i tried this -

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM table
WHERE a::BIGINT in( 303823703001,303823719403,303823675303);
```

However this did not work because the column 'a' is VARCHAR type and contains values which may have alphabets.

So i tried this -

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM table
WHERE a in( 303823703001::VARCHAR,303823719403::VARCHAR,303823675303::VARCHAR);
```

which worked!!

But my **ISSUE** is that i may have around 6000 comma separated numbers.
As a result the **query will get very bloated**.
I am looking to **convert all the comma separated numbers to VARCHAR in an easier way.**
Something like VARCHAR( 303823703001,303823719403,303823675303 )

The numbers that i get is from an excel sheet and these numbers are not stored in the db.

Comment: `where a in ('303823703001', '303823719403', '303823675303');` did not work?

Comment: @juergend yes it works like that but data is available to met without single quotes.

Comment: @juergend please help

Comment: Did you try using subquery for the IN values? What are you trying to do? Maybe there is a simpler way to achieve it.

Comment: Can you give example of subquery that you are mentioning.Can there be anything simpler than the current query ?

Comment: @Guy have you understood my question? I am looking to convert all the comma seperated numbers to VARCHAR in an easier way.

Comment: I understand that, I just don't understand why.

Comment: Here is a link to subquery examples: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery

Comment: Ok i know how to make subqeries but it will not help me since the numbers that i get is from an excel sheet and these numbers are not stored in the db.

Comment: Your best bet is to produce the list of strings as @juergend outlined. Try using the TEXTJOIN function in Excel, joining the strings with ',' as the separator. The end result will be quoted numbers, which you can then use straight way in the query.

Comment: @denismo Thanks. ( my purpose of this question was to know if this was possible through mysql/redshift which it isnt i guess)